# I'm having issues uninstalling pytorch

Tags: python, uninstallation, torch, torchvision, libtorch

So a while back I installed pytorch using pip and as a compute platform "CPU Only". Now I want to use torch on GPU but no matter how I try to install CUDA as a compute platform, it still always uses the version 1.9.0+cpu. Neither pip nor conda work on uninstalling it and I even tried to manually remove some torch files but with no help. No matter how much I try, it still always runs with the CPU computing device, and not with the CUDA support. I also tried creating different virtual envs and installing the CUDA there but it still works with the CPU version.

[When I try uninstalling with pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4rds.png)

[When I try uninstalling with conda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q6rO.png)

`import torch`

`print(torch.__version__)`

and this prints:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DakyR.png)

PS: I'm sorry the images are as links I don't have enough reputation for actual images apparently

Comment: You shouldn't post images in the first place, but use code blocks. Either way: try `print(torch.__file__)` to see where the installation is, or if that doesn't work, search through your computer for `torch`?

Comment: Noted, thank you! And the ```print(torch.__file__)``` really helped. I deleted the files and now finally it says no module found, so now I will try to reinstall the CUDA version. Thank you very much!

Comment: **Paste output samples and code as text instead of images** that's what @AKX said. Welcome to Stack Overflow, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my comment an answer you can accept:

You can use

```
print(torch.__file__)
```

to see where the mystery Torch installation is and delete it.

In case that doesn't work, you can always search your computer for `torch`.